# Require all function properties to have an "on" prefix

Tags: typescript, types

I want to type an object in which the keys can be either strings or numbers, except those keys that begin with the prefix "on" which must be a function like (...args: any[]) => any.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
type ValidProps = {
  [K in string]: K extends `on${string}` ? (...args: any[]) => any : (string | number)
};

const props: ValidProps = {
  a: "foo",
  b: 1,
  onC: () => {}, // TS complains here
};
```

[TypeScript playground reproduction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMAKAnA9mAzlAXigG8BYAKCigG0BpKJAOyl2AyYHMBdALinogAPYBEYp8AAyyMAJMVbtGHAL4SoAfigAKAHR64GDrj5xGIalwCUhAHxRTIKHy0LOUAD5RGAVwC2AIwgMSwplAG4KCgBjaVYoMGw8PnhkdET8IjJKez4AIgAzLCxcgBoKKn8%20AEYy7OkAYWdrAjtiZVrwiiA)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way. You'll have to use a generic type and a helper function [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mq04kN). Does that fully address the question? if so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that addresses the question. Unfortunately it won't be useful for my case as I don't want to introduce an additional function to perform type-checking but rather have the object itself back.
I was suspecting it wasn't possible so thanks to confirming. Your full answer might help other folks though.

Comment: Only you know your use case, but "I don't want" sounds like a preference and not an actual constraint.  I'll write an answer when I get a chance, but if I wish I knew what you meant by "have the object itself back", since maybe I could think if there's some other approach that would work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible only if the type of the non-`on` keys can be constructed.

For example, by limiting the keys to those beginning with lower-case characters, we can build a type of "keys that don't start with 'o' and keys that start with 'o' not followed by 'n'"

```
type Lower =
  |"a"|"b"|"c"|"d"|"e"|"f"|"g"|"h"|"i"|"j"|"k"|"l"|"m"
  |"n"|"o"|"p"|"r"|"s"|"t"|"u"|"v"|"w"|"z"|"y"|"z"

type NotOn =
  | `${Exclude<Lower, "o">}${string}`
  | `o${Exclude<Lower, "n">}${string}`,
```

It can then be used to define `ValidTypes`

```
type OnProps = Record<`on${string}`, (...args: never[]) => unknown>

type ValueProps = Record<NotOn, string | number>

type ValidProps = OnProps & ValueProps

const props: ValidProps = {
  a: "foo",
  b: 1,
  onC: () => {},
};
```

Types like that can cause issues with performance and readability. It is often better to define a limited set of keys, as in

```
type NotOn = "a" | "b"
```

Another common solution is to use a generic type to validate the type:

```
type ValidProps<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends `on${string}` ? (...args: never[]) => unknown : (string | number)
};

const props = {
  a: "foo",
  b: 1,
  onC: () => {}, // TS complains here
};

props satisfies ValidProps<typeof props>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in TypeScript as asked.  There is no specific type that works this way, since there's no way to express the type "every string that does not begin with `"on"`".  That would require *negated types* as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) but never merged.  Or, more generally, a specific type that meets your needs would require that TypeScript support a "rest index signature" or a "default index signature" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).  But for now, there is no such support.

The closest you can get to what you want is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, where the list of keys that actually show up in a type can be enumerated.  It could look like this:

```
type ValidProps<K extends PropertyKey> = {
  [P in K]: P extends `on${string}` ? (...args: any[]) => any : (string | number)
};
```

where `ValidProps<K>` is generic in `K`, the set of keys.  This would require people write

```
const props: ValidProps<"a" | "b" | "onC"> = {
  a: "foo",
  b: 1,
  onC: () => { },
};
```

which works, but is annoyingly redundant.  The redundancy can be sidestepped by writing a generic helper function to *infer* the type argument:

```
const validProps = <K extends PropertyKey>(v: ValidProps<K>) => v;

const props = validProps({
  a: "foo",
  b: 1,
  onC: () => { },
});
```

Now `props` is the same type as above, `ValidProps<"a" | "b" | "onC">`, but you didn't have to write out the type.  The helper function also catches errors:

```
const props2 = validProps({
  a: "foo",
  b: 1,
  c: () => { }, // error!
});
```

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it's fairly close. It does mean that functions that expect a `ValidProps` will have to become generic, and depending on the use case that's either simple (you can just add some more type parameters), or a dealbreaker (it would require such extensive refactoring that it's not worth it).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMAKAnA9mAzgHgGkoIAPYCAOxVykxwg1EIhAD4oBeKAbwFgAUFCgBtNFCSUohALoAuOiXJUaUAAZZKAEh65gGSQHMAvmqgB+KAAoAdHbgZDuBXEogRMgJRcOrkFAUrPQNKQygAHyhKAFcAWwAjRk9BYwBuQUEAY009KAA3RFR6PC4oIiUKalpixmZWNis8hXhkdGw8IjZvTg489IFsylywdtpuAtbi3Ct+ISg4BQAiADMsLEWAGkFheIUARi25zQBhQO6OHihjQ+NPfqyc4CgRnFwAJlKJotGZ7fml1brQ47fbAqCZM4+XhXDZQAD0cJIGGwGAAhCk7hkBIIgA)